# php - laravel 404 error when deploying live

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http-status-code-404

I'm getting a 404 error when I'm deploying my project on a live server. I'm getting a laravel page saying `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` so I know it is reaching my project.

I ran `php artisan config:cache`and `php artisan route:cache`to register my routes and cache, but it still isn't changing. not really sure why I'm getting this error. My document root in my vhost is set to my public folder as well.

**Steps I took to deploy**

1. cloned my project from git
2. changed branch to my develop branch
3. made my permissions for the project `777` (I know its wrong by I just wanted to get it to deploy and see if it had bugs)
4. pointed my vhost to `project/public`
5. added .env (was using it in previous deployment)
6. composer install
7. composer update
8. php artisan config:cache
9. php artisan route:cache

**vhost**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:443>
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/API/public
      #DocumentRoot /var/www/API/public/

      ServerName api.app.io
      ServerAlias api.app.io
      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/api-access.log combined

         <Directory "/var/www/API/public">
            #Options +Includes
            #Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

         </Directory>

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.app.io/cert.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.app.io/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.app.io/chain.pem
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    # RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handles JWT middleware
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please check and share the content of the log file from `storage/logs`

Comment: Nothing in there pertaining to this. last entry was from a bug I solved a little earlier.

Comment: @jermaynewilliams We can not solve the problem with this information, Please share more information

Comment: there may be a problem with your .htaccess file, or you are using a wrong version of PHP on your server. either way, if it's shared hosting, you can ask for the provider's help

Comment: @FatemehMajd What would the problem be in my `.htaccess` my php version is the same as my dev version

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya I updated my question.That's just about as much info as I can give. I dont get any other info from logs or anything

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but usually, something can be done in that area.

Comment: plus, I don't think just pointing vhost to that could be enough(I''m not sure about it though). you should use something like nginx and with it, point every request to the index.php file.

Comment: Did you any changes to the `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya No changes to those files. and I am using apache

Comment: Is your issue already resolved? If not, could you share your routes file?

Comment: What is your development OS and live server OS? It could be case sensitive, be careful with naming files

Comment: Take a really close look at your virtual host directives
```DocumentRoot /var/www/html/API/public``` and ```<Directory "/var/www/API/public">``` that's not right. I would also not name my project that way...
When you get a 404 error, just check the apache error log. and paste the relevant lines here in your original question.
You should check with 1 route, see if that works.
Don't change the original .htaccess file in /public to see if original Laravel works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change php version in your hosting panel.